# Is there any difference for installing Linux OS on desktop Vs Workstation?

Tags: centos, system-installation, gpu

I have a workstation of 250GB RAM with 32 CPU and 32 GPU Nvidia, Currently, it has a Red Hat OS but GPU's were not configured, also getting a problem to install OpenGL. I am thinking to install CentOS. Is there any difference between installing OS on desktop vs workstation?

Comment: Have you checked Nvidia for any linux drivers? I know when I run CentOS 7 at home, I still have to get drivers from the manufacturer to get the graphics card to work correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I have separate CD for that.

Answer (score 2):

CentOS is known to be a very stable distro, mainly because it uses Red Hat Linux as a base. I don't think there's a difference between PC vs workstation because a workstation is still a PC but then with higher hardware specs. You should take into account hardware support though. If it's CentOS, Nvidia should support it officially.

Answer (score 1):

'Workstation' is essentially a fancy name for a desktop system.  In some cases it may mean that the system in question uses some hardware conventionally used in servers (ECC RAM for example), but from a functional perspective it's no different from a desktop as far as Linux is concerned.